# Bedeutung von "Als ob!" in der Umgangssprache

Tags: meaning

Oft benutzt man in der Umgangssprache (Jugendsprache?) den Ausdruck "Als ob!" aber ohne den Konjunktiv und oft als ganzen Satz, als Reaktion, wobei man deutlich auf "ob" betont. Was hat es damit auf sich?

Comment: War nicht etwa *Und ob!* gemeint? *Als ob* kenne ich alleine stehend überhaupt nicht.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mein Sohn (7) verwendet es, wenn er eine Aussage keinen Glauben schenken kann. Ergänzt könnte es lauten

> **Als ob** das wahr wäre ...

Ich selbst (39) kenne diese Verwendung von früher gar nicht. Wir hätten eher

> Ja klar ...

oder

> Aber sicher ...

gesagt, jedoch nicht im Sinne "Logisch, ich hab es verstanden", sondern als "Du weißt, dass Du da Blödsinn erzählst".

Comment: Schöne Beschreibung. Zur Einordnung möchte ich noch darauf hinweisen, das der Ausdruck *Als ob* oftmals auch mit *Alter* ergänzt wird (*Als ob, Alter*). *Alter* steht hier nicht im Zusammenhang mit Lebensjahren sondern ist eine Übersetzung aus der türkischen Jugendsprache und ist soetwas wie ein Pronomen für Mitmensch. Ich vermute das sich *Als ob* durch die Rapper Szene verbreitet hat, ich bin mir dabei aber nicht sicher.

Comment: @ikadfoanhfda Auffällig dabei ist, dass es genau dem Englischen "as if!" entspricht. Kommt das vielleicht daher?

Comment: Eine kleine Grammatikkorrektur: *einer [Aussage].

Comment: @Jimi Jackson Lässt sich vermuten, meiner Meinung nach.

Comment: Wird es in Bezug auf eine positive Annahme gebraucht, ist "Schön wär's." wohl eine weitere Entsprechung.

Answer (score 2):

Ist definitiv ein Ausruf des Erstaunens, synonym mit "unglaublich".

Comment: Willkommen bei GSE! Wir bevorzugen eigentlich etwas längere Antworten, die außer "das ist so"  auch das Wieso und Warum einer Behauptung beleuchten.

Answer (score 2):

Offenbar hat sich im Sprachgebrauch dieses Ausdrucks im Laufe der Jahre etwas geändert.
Ich kenne den Ausdruck aus meiner Jugend im Sinne von "als ob das wahr wäre" oder "laber doch keinen Mist". Eine Aussage wird also drastisch in Zweifel gezogen.
Mein Sohn, jetzt selber Jugendlicher, benutzt ihn eher als ein Ausdruck des Erstaunens. Vergleichbar mit "unglaubich", "das kannn ja wohl nicht wahr sein", "das gibt's doch nicht" oder "irre, waas es alles gibt". Hier wird der Aussage eher zugestimmt, trotzdem man den Inahlt nicht erwartet hat.